# Laravel 5.1, creating global functions and creating new method for creating links from array

Tags: php, arrays, oop, laravel-5.1, global

Is there a simple way to build a list of links from a 1D array?

For example:

```
$array = [
    'slug-1' => 'Title 1',
    'slug-2' => 'Title 2',
    'slug-3' => 'Title 3'
]
```

echoed as:
    `<a href="slug-1">Title 1</a>, <a href="slug-2">Title 2</a>, <a href="slug-3">Title 3</a>`

Basicly a modified implode function with possibility of adding extra parameters as `class="something"` and similar.

I doubt there is so this is what I'm trying to do.

Create global functions:

- create `app/Http/helpers.php`
- edit `composer.json` by adding `"files": ["app/Http/helpers.php"]` in `autoload` block
- run `composer dump-autoload`

as described [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5?page=1).

Not sure how to proceed from here. I tried adding following code to the `helpers.php`:

```
<?php


/**
 * Given the array of type ['slug' => 'title', ...]
 * create new array of type [ '0' => '<a href="slug">title</a>', ...]
 * if $attributes given (also array) as ['id'=>'newLink', 'class'=>'newClass']
 * add them to first array to get <a href='slug' id='newLink' class='newClass'>title</a>
 *
 *
 * @param $array, $attributes
 * @return array
 */
public function linkifyArray($array, $attributes){
    $arrayOfLinks = $array;
    return $arrayOfLinks;
}
```

This does nothing but I tried to explain what I'm trying to do in the comments.

I believe I could create this function by myself but when I copy the code above to `helpers.php` file I'm getting internal server error and PHPStorm is telling me he's `expecting statement`.

So I'm missing something very basic here and would like some help (links are most welcome) before I can proceed to create my helper function.

Please tell me if I'm approaching this the wrong way.

In the end I want to be able to do following wherever in my app:

```
implode(', ', $array->linkifyArray())
```

to get list of links from `$array` in the beginning of this question.

EDIT:

I wrote the function:

```
public function linkifyArray($array, $attributes) {
    $htmlAttributes = '';
    //inline attributes before appending them to <a></a>
    if (is_array($attributes))
    {
        foreach ($attributes as $k => $v)
        {
            $htmlAttributes.= $k.'="'.$v.'" ';
        }
    }

    $arrayOfLinks = [];
    //create array of links
    if(is_array($array))
    {
        foreach ($array as $kk => $vv)
        {
            $arrayOfLinks[]='<a '.$htmlAttributes.' href="'.$kk.'">'.$vv.'</a>';
        }
    }

    return $arrayOfLinks;
}
```

and tried adding the `namespace App\Http;` below `<?php` but I'm still getting internal server error.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I got it to work.

`app/Http/helpers.php`

```
<?php

namespace app\Http;

class Helperfunctions {
    /**
     * Given the array of type ['slug' => 'title', ...]
     * create new array of type [ '0' => '<a href='slug'>title</a>]
     * if $attributes given (also array), implode them from ['id'=>'newLink', 'class'=>'newClass']
     * to <a href='slug' id='newLink' class='newClass'>title</a>
     *
     *
     * @param $array, $attributes, $prefix
     * @return array
     */
    public static function linkifyArray($array, $attributes, $prefix) {
        $htmlAttributes = '';
        //inline attributes before appending them to <a></a>
        if (is_array($attributes))
        {
            foreach ($attributes as $k => $v)
            {
                $htmlAttributes.= $k.'="'.$v.'" ';
            }
        }

        $arrayOfLinks = [];
        //create array of links
        if(is_array($array))
        {
            foreach ($array as $kk => $vv)
            {
                $arrayOfLinks[]='<a '.$htmlAttributes.' href="'.$prefix.$kk.'">'.$vv.'</a>';
            }
        }

        return $arrayOfLinks;
    }
}
```

Add to `composer.json` `autoload>classmap`:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/Http/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

Run

`composer dump-autoload`

Call the function in view as:

```
{!! implode(', ', \app\Http\Helperfunctions::linkifyArray($myModel()->get()->lists('name', 'slug')->toArray(), [], '/prefix-uri/')) !!}
```

[Link](http://vegibit.com/custom-helper-functions-in-laravel/) to the tutorial I used.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen, that you figured a solution up for yourself. But if you don't want to handle this kind of stuff with classes you could use the approach of your original answer. The only thing is, that in your helpers.php file you must not use keywords like public etc...

You have to see this just like a bunch of functions that are not bundled within a class. And outside a class the public keyword causes the error.

Just define your functions in the following way inside your helper.php :

```
<?php 

function linkifyArray($array, $attributes, $prefix) {
    // code
}
```

Then you can access it in your application by just typing ( example taken from your answer )

```
{!! implode(', ', linkifyArray($myModel()->get()->lists('name', 'slug')->toArray(), [], '/prefix-uri/')) !!}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just got notified about this. It makes sense to me now. My problem is that I'm self taught so although I manage around I still end up missing some really basic stuff :/

Answer (score 0):

```
public function linkifyArray($array, $attributes){
    $arrayOfLinks = $array;
    $html = "";
    $id = "";
    $class = "";
    if($attributes['id'])
    $id = $attributes['id'];
    if($attributes['class'])
    $class = $attributes['class'];
    foreach($arrayOfLinks as $key=>$val)
    {
    $html.="<a href='".$key."' id='".$id."' class='".$class."'>".$val."</a>";
    }
    return $html;
  }
```

Comment: Yes, thats what I had in mind, however I'm doing something wrong because I'm getting `Internal error` whenever I include anything in that `helpers.php` file. The iterations shouldn't be the problem, I'm having difficulties with internal error thing and I have little idea how this works because I'm doing this global function thing for the first time. I guess the approach is ok then?

Comment: Yes, the approach is ok, probabbly a problem with autoload then.

Comment: It seems that adding `namespace App\Http;` below the `<?php` could be solution. I'll be back when everything is working to confirm.

Comment: If you are using global App namespace, then yes.

Comment: Use chrome inspect element and switch to network tab then refresh and check the output

Comment: I got it working and added the complete how-to. Thank you for your help and if you see something wrong please do tell. Živio!

Comment: the error occurs becaus of public keyword. If you don't have a class then access modifiers are not valid. Just remove the public from public function() ... and it should work

Comment: Thank you very much @shock_gone_wild . Just to be sure I got it right: `public`, `protected`, and `private` keywords should be only used for functions inside of a class otherwise they don't make sense and give error?